# Angular Universal view page source

Tags: angular-universal, angular-seo

I have implemented Angular Universal in angular 5 app. However, I could not see meta tags, source code in the view page source. When I inspect code in the developer tool, i see meta tags, keywords. But not in the source code. SEO Checker also could not find keywords. Is it normal?

Comment: No it's not normal; the principle of angular universal is to have the meta rendered server side. ANy errors in the console server side?

Comment: till yesterday there was no errors, but now it does not work without writing www.example.com/index.html, it throws an error like  -  Error: The XMLHttpRequest compatibility library was not found. i could not find any solution in the internet